# MySQL Multiple select queries with different result lengths

Tags: mysql, select, count

I am trying to run two sql select statments at once, one to count the number of rows and the other to return the values from "search_names". I'm getting the error "subquery returns more than one row" because rowcount only has one value to return while searchresults returns many. Is there a way to run these statments together or will I need to split them up?

```
SELECT(  
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM user_searches 
    WHERE `user_id` = 15
    AND `read` = 0 
    ) 
AS rowcount, 
    (
    SELECT `search_name` 
    FROM user_searches 
    WHERE `user_id` = 15
    ) 
AS searchresults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_searches WHERE `user_id` = 15 AND `read` = 0)
    AS rowcount,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`search_name`) AS searchresults
FROM user_searches WHERE `user_id` = 15
```

The thing is you can't return in a row value a whole dataset. But you can return a comma separated list of all search names. Then from your program you can easily parse this list.

Comment: This query would return a different result than the example as you apply the `read = 0` condition to search_name too, which the example doesn't.

Comment: jpw is right, I get the wrong count with that query. You were on the right track with GROUP_CONCAT however, this seems to be what I need:
 

SELECT(  
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM user_searches 
        WHERE `user_id` = 15
        AND `read` = 0 
        ) 
    AS rowcount, 
        (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`search_name`) 
        FROM user_searches 
        WHERE `user_id` = 15
        ) 
    AS searchresults